# Associating Sagemaker results with input columns

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am using a Sagemaker XGBoost for building my classification model.
I am trying to compare "actuals" vs "predictions" across 10 risk BINs.

The model has already been trained and deployed.

Here are my input data columns:

EID, ACTUAL, INPUT1, INPUT2, INPUT3, INPUT4, INPUT 5

Here is my code:

```
import json
import io
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_csv_output_from_s3(s3uri, file_name):
    parsed_url = urlparse(s3uri)
    bucket_name = parsed_url.netloc
    prefix = parsed_url.path[1:]
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, '{}{}'.format(prefix, file_name))

    return obj.get()["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')   


# content_type / accept and split_type / assemble_with are required to use IO joining feature
transform_job.assemble_with = 'Line'
transform_job.accept = 'text/csv'

# start a transform job
transform_job.transform(new_tenure_input_full_path, split_type='Line', content_type='text/csv', input_filter='$[1:]', join_source='Input', output_filter="$[0,-1]")
transform_job.wait()

output_n = get_csv_output_from_s3(output_full_path,'Output.csv.out')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(output_n), sep=",", names=['EID', 'RAW_SCORE'])

out, bins = pd.qcut(df['RAW_SCORE'], q=10, retbins=True)

# Group events into count
counts = []
for lower, upper in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:]):
    bin_data = df.query(f'{lower} < RAW_SCORE <= {upper}')
    events_count= sum(bin_data['ACTUAL'])
    emp_count = bin_data.shape[0]
    counts.append({"events_count": events_count, "emp_count": emp_count, "upper_limit": upper, "lower_limit": lower})
```

The binning part works fine.

The output file has EID and RAW_SCORE but I am unable to get the third column ACTUAL from the Batch Transform job.

This has to be done in this line:

```
input_filter='$[1:]', join_source='Input', output_filter="$[0,-1]"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With "output_filter="$[0,-1]", you'll only get the first and last column of the joined input and output, which are EID and RAW_SCORE.

To include ACTUAL, you should change the output filter to include one more column, e.g. "output_filter="$[0, 1, -1]", assuming ACTUAL is the second column of your original input data, not the filtered one, as joining is based on the original input and output, then output filter is applied to get the final results.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform-data-processing.html for more info.

Comment: Thank you @Alohahaha. So you could add the column indexes of all columns you will need in the output? I will try this.